# Invoke click on a button within div

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm working on a client-side application that needs to click on a certain button within a webpage. Because there are multiple buttons on the page with the same class & id, I need to add an additional constrain to ensure the right button is clicked.

As example this is the source code of the specific button that needs to be clicked.

```
<div class="buttondiv" data-id="118">
    <button type="button" class="special"></button>
</div>
<div class="buttondiv" data-id="119">
    <button type="button" class="special"></button>
</div>
```

Something similar like this should do the job:

```
if ((div id == "118") && (button class == special))
{
    element.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

Any advice how to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason not to do this with Javascript or even jQuery?

Comment: Also, it's not valid to have multiple controls with the same ID. ID must be unique within the DOM.

Comment: Having multiple ID's on the same page is not valid HTML. If there is some reason you cannot change the ID's, you can select elements based on other criteria such as class names, data- attributes, proximity to other elements, etc... The best way to achieve this would be to use Javascript or jQuery to handle the buttton click events, and then your C# code can pick it up on the server.